# From Where does data gets pulled WITH NOLOCK option..tables in Harddisk or from data pages

Tags: sql-server

This might be a silly Question but if we use WITH (NOLOCK) option where does the sql server pulls the data from...Disk or Data pages.

```
begin transaction
Update table1
set col1 = 'abc'
```

In the above code I have not given Commit or rollback statement so data pages will get locked. But with NOLOCK option i can read the records that are not committed yet. select * from Table1 with (NOLOCK) seems to read the data from the table but Records go to the table only after the commit statement and in this case I have not issued any commit statement. So my question is that in this case sql server reads the modified data from DISK or Data pages.

As per my understanding sql follows below mentioned steps:

1. When a DML statements like INSERT UPDATE or DELETE are issued sql server first finds the records in data pages if not found then it loads the records in the data pages.
2. checks constraints rules.
3. Modification in the data pages are done.
4. Transaction entry is done in the Transaction log.
5. SQl server writes the data to the harddisk.
6. Issues checkpoint which is also recorded in the Transaction log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some of the subtleties of SQL.  Uncommitted changes can indeed go to disk, just not to the database data file (ndf/ndf), but even that isn't relevant for this question.  `WITH (NOLOCK)` queries can read data from any in-progress transactions regardless of whether or not they have been committed.  They can also skip data that has been deleted and not yet committed as well.  This only makes a difference if the transactions are rolled back or if you care that you might get some results from a transaction without getting other results from the same transaction.